# Open WatchKit application from iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I would like to open WatchKit application to the foreground (or Glance if it is possible) directly from my iPhone.

I've been playing with it, but have no success. Maybe someone have found some workarounds?

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone app can't launch the Apple Watch app in the current WatchKit version. The only possible way is to launching the iPhone app from the WatchKit app in the background, or using Handoff to move between the two companion apps in a jiffy.

NOTE: The best way is always waiting for the new versions. WWDC 2015 takes place in San Francisco in June 8-12, and they will introduce WatchKit 2 alongside with new versions of OS X and iOS. WatchKit 2 will support the missing APIs and Apple Watch native apps (which run on the Apple Watch without having iPhone nearby).

Answer (score 1):

So answer is **No, you can't open Watchkit App from iPhone**.

The WatchKit extension can only request the system to launch the parent iPhone app, which it will run in the background.

There is currently no support for this to work the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, Its not possible as of now.

Let's hope Apple add that support & release it in coming WWDC.

Answer (score 1):

During the WWDC 2015 session "Introducing WatchKit for watchOS 2", an Apple developer mentioned this is **not possible** even with the new version of WatchKit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to launch the Watchkit app from the iPhone, only the opposite way is possible (Apple Watch launches the iPhone app in background mode).